# Conceptual: How do I get the queries/inputs a user enters inside a form, and append or pass them onto an external API call inside an express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, crud

I want to get data from an external API, but the data returned is contingent on user selection, and depending on what the user selects I want those fields to be passed to the API call url. I just wanted to know, if I am on the right track?

How can I ensure that they are being attached to the endpoint?

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Based on what the user selects, you can send different values to the API. If you have a more concrete example with code, you may get more helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch foe changes in the input boxes, and then you can call the api with the necessary endpoint, for example:

let's suppose you have a endpoint like this

'https://someapi.com/users?name=Name'  <= variable Name, for example

you can make a request based on the name you get from the input boxes, wich can be stored in a variable or in state (depends on what you're using).

if you want to know that you're doing the right thing, logging things to the console helps a lot